# .htaccess não funciona

Tags: php, htaccess, apache

Olá, eu já uso essas regras do .htaccess e nunca me deu problema, tanto que uso em outros provedores atualmente, gostaria de saber se a versão do apache ou a do php no servidor de hospedagem atrapalha na execução das rules.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^produto(|/)$ produto.php
RewriteRule ^produto/(.*)$ produto.php/$1

ErrorDocument 403 //403.php
ErrorDocument 404 //404.php
ErrorDocument 500 //500.php
```

A versão do PHP é 5.5, o provedor não da acesso a versão do apache, atualmente, roda em Linux 5.2.
O Site de hospedagem é a locaweb.

Comment: Já tentastes trocar `produto.php/$1` por `produto.php?/$1`?

Comment: Já, não funcionou.

Comment: Então, faça as primeiras edições: `//` não são comentários válidos nos arquivos de configuração do Apache. `ErrorDocument` precisa do segundo parâmetro: `ErrorDocument <3-digit-code> <action>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como não estava conseguindo corrigir o problema com a solução que funciona no meu server, tive que mudar o código que faz buscar os dados no banco, então alterei para um `GET` na página e adicionei um `foreach` e modifiquei o .htaccess.

.htaccess ficou:

```
RewriteRule ^produto(|/)$ produto.php?/id=$1
RewriteRule ^produto/(.*)$ produto.php?id=$1
```

a página ficou:

```
$prod = $_GET['id'];
$muda_path = explode('/', $prod);
foreach($muda_path as $produto){...}
```